# Как достать значение из поля комментарий и записать его в переменную в бизнес процессе? Помогите пожалуйста

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

Создаю БП Увольнение. После ряда действий, гл. бух в комментариях пишет сумму расчета, мне надо эту сумму записать в переменную и выслать на согласование к директору. Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если используете *Задания бизнес процессов*, то результаты после их выполнения можно получить в *Дополнительных результатах* (см. доку: [Функции калькулятора выражений](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=48&LESSON_ID=4912&LESSON_PATH=3918.4635.4744.5059.4912)).

А вообще, лучше в задание БП добавить специальную переменную. И пусть пользователь её заполняет, а не в штатном поле "Комментарий" пишет. Тем более, если это число.

Answer (score 0):

В параметрах шаблона БП добавьте свою переменную, чтобы хранить эту сумму расчёта. Затем в шаблоне, после того блока где бухгалтер оставляет комментарий, добавьте блок "Изменение переменных", в нём укажите эту переменную, а в значении выберите "дополнительные результаты -> блок где бухгалтер оставляет комментарий -> комментарии".
Затем можете эту переменную добавлять к сообщениям или куда вам необходимо.